# How to Show Zero Count in SQL SERVER Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to know that how we can display ZERO count? I have only one table and I am doing monthly count but some how 1 month doesn't have any rows and SQL Server is skipping that month during count but I need to show in my report.

This is my query that I am using:

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(createdDate) [Month], 
    ISNULL(COUNT(id), 0) [Count]
FROM 
    [PocketLife].[dbo].[Notifications]
WHERE 
    description = 'Welcome to Pocket Link' AND 
    YEAR(CAST(createdDate as DATE)) = YEAR(GETDATE())
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(createdDate)
```

Currently the above query is showing like this but it is missing the First Month Record which is ZERO.

```
Month   Count
--------------
2            5 
3          295 
4         8295 
5       149855 
6       447752 
7         6311
```

But it should Show as below and this is the actual Result:

```
Month   Count
--------------
1            0 
2            5 
3          295 
4         8295 
5       149855 
6       447752 
7         6311
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this record satisfy both where conditions?. Your query looks fine and it should return what you need.

Comment: Why stop at `Month = 7`? Why not until `12`?

Comment: **Ala**  Yes Both conditions are OK but it is just not return the Null or Zero Record.

Comment: **Wewesthemenace:** because it is only for current year. so until now in 2015, we just reach July. so rest don't have records. so no need to show.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! You don't need any of those messy `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` tags, either!

Comment: You have got some nice hacking solutions. But I highly suggest that you try to find the root cause of your problem. Again, your query looks fine but your record is problematic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Tally Table ranging from 1 - 12 for the list of months, then do a `LEFT JOIN` on your query. Add an additional filter for `N` so that it only returns records up to the current month.

*Replace the content of `Cte` with your original query.*

```
WITH Cte([Month], [Count]) AS(
    SELECT 2, 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 295 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 8295 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 149855 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 447752 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7, 6311
),
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
)
SELECT
    t.N AS [Month],
    ISNULL(c.Count, 0) AS [Count]
FROM CteTally t
LEFT JOIN Cte c
    ON t.N =c.Month
WHERE
    t.N <= MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: +1 - You could even use `VALUES` rather than all those `UNION ALL` statements. Something like `SELECT * FROM  (VALUES(1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) M(Months)`

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of weird, but you could just go

```
SELECT 0 [Month], 0 [Count]
UNION ALL
SELECT MONTH(createdDate) [Month], ISNULL(COUNT(id), 0) [Count]
      FROM [PocketLife].[dbo].[Notifications]
        WHERE description = 'Welcome to Pocket Link' AND 
          YEAR(CAST(createdDate as DATE)) = YEAR(GETDATE())
            GROUP BY MONTH(createdDate)
```

Comment: **Maxymoo** Thank you very Much. Working Great. 

but is there any way to make this query result more faster ??

Answer (score 1):

Probably this could be helpful to you.

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare  @LastMonth     Int = 1

Select  @LastMonth = Datepart(Month, Max(n.createdDate))
From    [PocketLife].[dbo].[Notifications] As n With (Nolock)

;With MonthCte As
(
    Select  1 As [Month]

    Union All

    Select  ([Month] + 1)
    From    MonthCte As m
    Where   m.[Month] < @LastMonth
)

Select   mc.[Month]
        ,ISNULL(COUNT(id), 0) [Count]
From    MonthCte As mc With (Nolock)
        Left Join [PocketLife].[dbo].[Notifications] As n On mc.[Month] = Datepart(n.createdDate)
Where   description = 'Welcome to Pocket Link'
        AND YEAR(CAST(createdDate as DATE)) = YEAR(GETDATE()
Group By mc.[Month]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @year int
set @year = YEAR(GETDATE())

;with mths as(
    select 1 as mth, DATENAME(MONTH, cast(@year*100+1 as varchar) + '01')  as monthname
union all
    select mth+1, DATENAME(MONTH, cast(@year*100+(mth+1) as varchar) + '01') from mths where mth<MONTH(GETDATE()) 
)
select  m.mth Month, isnull(count,0) as Count
from    mths m 
left join (
    select   MONTH([createdDate]) as Month,COUNT([id]) as Count
    from     [Notifications]
    where    YEAR([createdDate]) = @year 

    group by MONTH([createdDate])
 ) s on m.mth = s.Month
```

Comment: **Gisha Ajeesh** Thank you very Much. Working Great. but is there any way to make this query result more faster ??